# Javascript: how to un-surroundContents range

Tags: javascript, dom

This function uses the range object to return user selection and wrap it in bold tags. is there a method that allows me to remove the tags? As in `<b>text<b>`  = `text`. 

 
I actually need a toggle function that wraps the selection in tags & un-wraps it if already contains tags. Similar to what text editors do when you toggle the bold button.

```
if "text" then "<b>text</b>"
else "<b>text</b>" then "text"
```

...

```
function makeBold() {

    //create variable from selection
    var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount) {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        var newNode = document.createElement("b");

            //wrap selection in tags
        range.surroundContents(newNode);

            //return the user selection
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't mention this in your previous question about this because it sounded like you wanted a generic means of surrounding a range within an element, but for this particular application (i.e. bolding/unbolding text), and assuming you don't mind a little cross-browser variation in the precise tags used (`<strong>` versus `<bold>` versus possibly `<span style="font-weight: bold">`), you're best off using `document.execCommand()`, which will toggle boldness:

```
function toggleBold() {
    document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
}
```

This will work in all browsers when the selected content is editable, and even when it's not editable in IE. If you need it to work on non-editable content in other browsers, you'll need to temporarily make the document editable:

```
function toggleBold() {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // Non-IE case
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        document.designMode = "on";
        if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange &&
            document.selection.type != "None") {
        // IE case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("bold", false, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: That execCommand() is marvelous. I wonder why no one is using it. That's the first time I hear about it!

Comment: `execCommand` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

wrapping & **un-wrapping** the text selection using the same button click event handler:

```js
boldBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let selection = document.getSelection();
  
  const isAllowedContainer = selection.baseNode.parentElement?.closest?.('#editor');
  
  // do not continue if no text selection or this is not the desired element container
  if( selection.rangeCount < 1 || !isAllowedContainer ) return;
  
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  const selParent = selection.anchorNode?.parentElement;
  const selectedElem = selParent?.nodeType == 1 && selParent?.children.length < 2 && selParent;
  
  // un-wrap
  if(selectedElem.tagName === 'B') {
    selectedElem.replaceWith(...selectedElem.childNodes)
  }
 
  // wrap with <b>
  else {
    range.surroundContents(document.createElement("b"));
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    range.collapse(); // removes selected and places caret at the end of the injected node
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="boldBtn">B</button><br/><br/>
<div id='editor' contenteditable="true">Select some text and click the button</div>
```