# How to get the marked text with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement the `make bold` and `put underline` functions on my own. For this, I need to get the text which is marked like this:

[image]

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: You mean that you want to find all texts containing 'text which is marked' and make them bold and underlned?

Comment: @MariaIoannidou, i have a button called ``BOLD``, i want that if user selects a word or sentence and hits ``BOLD``, the selected text should get bold or should be set in between some signs like ``<b>``

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac) and http://jsfiddle.net/dKaJ3/2/

Comment: @PalashMondal, i cannot attach click event, http://jsfiddle.net/NjW5a/36/  can you pls take a look

Answer (score 4):

```
var start = element.selectionStart;
var end = element.selectionEnd;
var sel = element.value.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to adapt. This[0] was the element of which u want to get the selected text

Comment: Is this reliable cross-browser?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351455/make-selected-text-bold-using-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479151/javascript-how-to-un-surroundcontents-range) questions, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8D6as/2/) demo shows how you can implement make bold and toggle bold functionality on selected text.

The js function to make selected text bold is:

```
function makeBold() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount) {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        var newNode = document.createElement("b");
        range.surroundContents(newNode);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. However, please don't use the "b"-tag, it should be "strong".